# store for model is undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to write a frontend with ember.js and ember-data for a REST service. The server returns the data (I do see this using fiddler) but I always get the error `Unable to set property 'store' of undefined or null reference`.  My JS code:

```
window.Cube = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true
});

var attr = DS.attr;

Cube.Subject = DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr(),
    change_date: attr(),
    create_date: attr()
});

Cube.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'backend/v1/api',
    host: 'http://localhost:58721'
});

Cube.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    url: "http://localhost:58721",
    adapter: Cube.ApplicationAdapter
});

Cube.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        var store = this.get('store');
        return store.findAll('Subject');
    }
});
```

The error originates in ember-data.js:

```
modelFor: function(key) {
    if (typeof key !== 'string') {
        return key;
    }

    var factory = this.container.lookupFactory('model:'+key);

    Ember.assert("No model was found for '" + key + "'", factory);

    factory.store = this; // error here
    factory.typeKey = key;

    return factory;
}
```

As far as I understand ember, the store should be automatically set, but it is always null.

How to define the model, so the store is available? What am I missing?

**Update 1:**
Updated ember. Now I use the following versions:

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.1.0
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.3
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.0.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.9.1
```

No I get the following errors in the console:

```
No model was found for 'nextObject'
Error while loading route: TypeError: Unable to set property 'store' of undefined or null reference
```

Answer (score 0):

subject should be lower case, additionally findAll is an internal method, you should be using find with no additional parameters (which then calls findAll).

```
Cube.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    var store = this.get('store');
    return store.find('subject');
  }
});
```

Comment: Still the same error. Acccording to http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-all-records-of-a-type/ you should use findAll to get all records

Comment: Which version of Ember Data are you using?  I just noticed your construction of ED store is old

Comment: It's 1.0.0 when I look into ember.js and the latest ember-data

Comment: Used 1.0.0, updated to 1.1.0 (also updated my post), error still there

Comment: Latest Ember Data, meaning 1.0 beta 3?  If so you are declaring a few things incorrectly.  You probably want to read through this transition documentation, https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md